# Can't upload image from React using Wordpress Media Rest API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a React app (with create-react-app) and I need to upload images in a Wordpress website, using Wordpress Media Rest API. I'm running the react app locally (http://localhost:3000/test)
In the Wordpress website I am using 'JWT Authentication for WP-API' plugin for easier authentication.

When I try to upload the image, it gives me a '400 - Bad Request' response with the following details:

```
{"code":"rest_upload_no_data","message":"No data supplied.","data":{"status":400}}
```

I've been searching and trying all solutions I found the last 3 days. None of them works.

My implementation details:

In wp-config, I did all the changes described in the [plugin's page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/).

**WP Server .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 
#RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Accept"
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 260M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off

</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 260M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

**React**

```
const Test = () => {

    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false)
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null)
    const blockScreenContext = useContext(BlockScreenUIContext)

    const fileUploadHandler = e => {

        e.preventDefault();

        //setting the data that will parsed with the file
        let oDate = new Date();
        let wpMediaData = {
            title: 'Posted from App',
            caption: 'The post caption text'
        }


        //creating the form data object and appending the extra info for the file
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (var key in wpMediaData) {
            formData.append(key, wpMediaData[key])
        }

        formData.append('file', selectedFile)
        //formData.append('file', document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0])

        //defining the base url
        let baseUrl = 'https://mywebsite.com/'


        //getting the token
        let token = 'my token'

            let headers = {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2),
                'Content-Disposition': `form-data; filename="${selectedFile.name}"`,
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            }


            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                headers: headers
            }

            let url = baseUrl + 'wp-json/wp/v2/media'

            fetch( url, options).then(res => {
                console.log('response', res)

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('error', err)
            })


    }

    const fileSelectedHandler = e => {
        //the first element of the target is the file
        console.log('o valor obtido com e.target', e.target.files[0])
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])
    }

    return <div>
        <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div className="form-group">
                <input id="file" name="file" type="file" className="form-control" onChange={fileSelectedHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <BSButton
                    type='submit'
                    className='btn-primary'
                    text="Upload"
                    loadingText="Uploading..."
                    onClick={fileUploadHandler}
                    disable={isUploading}
                />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
}
```

For Content Disposition, I also tried:

```
Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${selectedFile.name}
```

I tried to use Axios instead, and had the same problem.
All other requests with Wordpress are working fine.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First try the api with a rest client like postman and find whether the issue is with the client side or server side. This must be the first step to do.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC I also tried that, and got the same response. In my case, i used Insomnia.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a separated re-usable method for media uploading using `@wordpress/api-fetch` which is now a good standard for fetching/storing data in WordPress.

```js
// Import api-fetch Library
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

/**
 * Upload a media file.
 *
 * @param {Object} file
 * @param {Object} additionalData
 *
 * @return {Promise} A promise representing the request processed via the registered middlewares.
 */
export function uploadMedia(file, additionalData = {}) {
    const data = new window.FormData();
    data.append('file', file, file.name || file.type.replace('/', '.'));

    if (additionalData) {
        Object.entries(additionalData).forEach(([key, value]) =>
            data.append(key, value)
        );
    }

    return apiFetch({
        path: '/wp/v2/media',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    });
}
```

And then call this method easily as your needs.

```js
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => uploadMedia(e.target.files[0])} />
```

Hope, this will help many ones in future.

Answer (score 0):

It was a full day of my experiments,
but it works!

1. button MEDIA in this repository https://github.com/fotomain/react-wordpress-auth-starter/blob/master/src/App.js
2. define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);